How to solve the error unable to detect project KGP version. Skipping version checking. on Flutter /Android studio
I'm currently having the following error in Flutter /Android studio
I couldn't find any help on google:

Warning: unable to detect project KGP version. Skipping version
checking.  This may be because you have applied KGP after the Flutter
Gradle Plugin.
e:
/Users/.../android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/esosba_app/MainActivity.kt:
(3, 8): Unresolved reference: io e:
/Users/.../android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/esosba_app/MainActivity.kt:
(5, 21): Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity

this is my Gradle :
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
       
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "8.0.0"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10"
   id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
 namespace 'com.example.esosba_app' // Fügen Sie diesen Eintrag hinzu
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.esosba_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // TODO: Hier sollte ein //Signatur-Konfigurationsblock angefügt werden.
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"

   
}

And my MainActivity.kt
package com.example.esosba_app

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you very much

You may need to change your gradle files according to this.
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
I can see some differences in your gradle. Make sure that you change your app level gradle, root level gradle and gradle settings according to the above article.

inside android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties just change distributionUrl to :
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

or
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip


First you may need to change your gradle files according to this. https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
Then in your app/build.gradle, make sure to move kotlin-android above "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" // if you are using google-services
}


Please make sure your answer is useful without clicking the link
